# Running airflow behind a reverse proxy with ProxyFix

Tags: python, proxy, reverse-proxy, airflow, werkzeug

Trying to setup airflow to run behind a reverse proxy as described here:
https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/run-behind-proxy.html

I'm running airflow v1.10.3 and I enabled ProxyFix:

```
[webserver]
enable_proxy_fix = True
```

Confirmed it was correctly started up in the webserver logs:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www_rbac/app.py:48: DeprecationWarning: 'werkzeug.contrib.fixers.ProxyFix' has moved to 'werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix.ProxyFix'. This import is deprecated as of version 0.15 and will be removed in 1.0.
```

And then ran the following:

````
curl http://localhost:8080 --header "X-Forwarded-Host: airflow.staging.spothero.com" -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> X-Forwarded-Host: airflow.staging.spothero.com
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 17:14:54 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 217
< Location: http://localhost:8080/home```
````

```
curl http://localhost:8080 --header "Host: airflow.staging.spothero.com" -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://localhost:8080/
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: airflow.staging.spothero.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 FOUND
< Server: gunicorn/19.9.0
< Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2019 17:21:27 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 217
< Location: http://airflow.staging.spothero.com/home
```

And you can see the redirect is generated correctly with the `Host` header but incorrectly with the `X-Forwarded-Host` header. ProxyFix *should* use the `X-Forwarded-Host` header instead of the `Host` header when generating these redirects, but for some reason it is not.

Any ideas on what configuration I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Found the root cause, it had to do with different werkzeug versions (I was running 0.15.x not 0.14.x).

https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.14.x/contrib/fixers/
https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/middleware/proxy_fix/#module-werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix

By default, the `0.15.x` version requires setting `x_host=1` in order to trust the first `X-Forwarded-Host` header, otherwise ProxyFix will ignore the header entirely. Airflow does not provide hooks to set this property out of the box, so airflow's ProxyFix does not work with werkzeug `0.15.x`.

`0.14.x` trusts the first header by default, but it is incompatible with flask >=1.10 which airflow uses:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4900

This has been fixed in airflow 1.10.4:
https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5563